# Django: How to trigger events based on datetimes in the database

Tags: python, django, database, celery, django-celery

I have a simple Django app with a database which stores a series of messages and datetime at which I want them to printed to screen.  Is there a way to have Django call a method which would check to see if any new messages needed printing and, if so, print them?

I have heard about celery for scheduling tasks but it seems to be massively overkill for what I need.

Comment: On what system are you running your app? If you are on Linux or Unix (or OS X) then you could setup a cronjob that runs every N minutes to execute a custom `manage.py` command. This command can check the database and execute your business logic for unprocessed messages.

Comment: sthzg's solution is easy to implement and quite lightweight. I'd recommend doing that unless you need very accurate timing (cronjob will be +/- 1minute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the clarification for your use case in the comment to Stewart's answer, I suggest using `cronjobs` and a custom `manage.py` command.

---

**Model**
To filter out all notifications that haven't been sent it is a good idea to have a flag on the model, e.g. `is_notified = models.BooleanField(default=False)`. This way it becomes fast and easy to filter the necessary messages, e.g. with `MyModel.objects.filter(is_notified=False, 'send_on__lte': datetime.now())`.

---

**A custom manage.py command**
In the custom `manage.py` command you have full access to your Django setup. Writing them is documented in [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/).

The command will usually (at least):

- filter all notifications that should be sent
- iterate over them and try to send the email
- when successful, set `is_notified` to `True` and save the instance

---

**Cronjob**
The [cronjob](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) is easy to setup. `$ crontab -l` will list all cronjobs that are currently installed. `$ crontab -e` will open the default editor (probably vi(m) or nano) to add new cronjobs.

Example: running command every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/foobar/my-virtualenv/bin/python /home/foobar/my-django-dir/manage.py my_django_command >> /home/logs/my_django_command.log 2>&1
```

Adding is done by pasting the snippet to a new line in the file that opens after calling `$ crontab -e` and saving the file.

**`*/5 * * * *`**
specifies to run the cronjob every five minutes.

**`/home/foobar/my-virtualenv/bin/python`**
specifies to call Python from your *virtualenv* (if you use one) rather than the system version.

**`/home/foobar/my-django-dir/manage.py my_django_command`**
calls your *manage.py* command just like you would do.

**`>> /home/logs/my_django_command.log 2>&1`**
specifies that all output (standard output and errors) generated by the *manage.py* command will be saved to the file *my_django_command.log*. Just make sure that the directories (in this case *home/logs*) exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need them printed to the page without the user refreshing the page in their browser? If so, you need to write some JavaScript AJAX code to continuously poll your application view for new content to write to the page.

Here's an example tutorial on AJAX using Django: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Comment: You have a point: @JMzance: where are those messages supposed to be displayed?

Comment: In the production version they will actually be emailed out - so this approach wont work.  I was hoping there was a way to do it just using django

Comment: Then just override related model's save method or use signals to catch when a new record is registered in the database.

Comment: I dont see how a post-save/-init signal would help?  If I save an event into the DB which I want to fire this time tomorrow (for example) - how will a post-save deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `cron` then you could use [django-cronograph](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/).